# How to allow user to add multiple values to array with php?

Tags: php

I have this php file that allows a user to enter their favorite music artist. My program puts the entered artist in a variable called "art" and then adds it to an array called "artist". Then it displays the array in a bullet list. But the program as it is only allows one value to be in the array. When the user enters another artist, it overwrites the one that is already in the array. For example, the user writes "bob" as their favorite artist and presses submit. The program displays bob, but when you go to put in another artist, "tess", bob is gone and only tess is diplayed. How do i fix this?

Here is the code: (Don't mind the commented out echo, it was a test to see if the entered value was being assigned to the variable.)

```
<h1> My Favorite Artist </h1>
        
            <form method='POST'>
                <h3>Please enter your favorite artist</h3>
                <input type="text" name="artist">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Artist">
    
            </form>
    <?php
    $art = $_POST['artist'];
    //echo "<h3> This $art </h3>";
    $artist = array();
    array_push($artist, $art);
    

    foreach ($artist as $a)
    {
        echo "<li>$a</li>";
    }




?>
```

Comment: You need to process the value of $_POST['artist'] into an array. Try splitting the values by a common delimiter (comma for example) using the 'explode' function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). 'explode' function will give you an array of values which you can then load into the $artist array.

Comment: Sounds like you want to persist the `$artist` array between requests. Using session storage seems a good fit

Answer (score 1):

You can try by creating a session of array and then print it like this.

```
<?php

    session_start();

?>
<h1> My Favorite Artist </h1>
        
            <form method='POST'>
                <h3>Please enter your favorite artist</h3>
                <input type="text" name="artist">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Artist">
    
            </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['artist']))
    {
        
    $art = $_POST['artist'];
    //echo "<h3> This $art </h3>";
    if(empty($_SESSION['artist']))
    {
        $_SESSION['artist'] = array();
    }
    array_push($_SESSION['artist'], $art);
    
    
    $arry=$_SESSION['artist'];
    if(!empty($arry))
    {
        foreach ($arry as $a)
        {
            echo "<li>$a</li>";
        }
    }
    }
```